# query the spdlog logger name

Tags: c++, spdlog

say we build our spdlog object as the following?

```
logger = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>("some name", sink_list.begin(), sink_list.end());
```

Is there a method such as `logger->get_name()` or anything else that would return "some name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a method such as `logger->get_name()` or anything else that would return "some name"

There is.

```
logger->name()
```

[(source)](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/v1.x/include/spdlog/logger-inl.h#L77)